# How to create an API Client with endpoints in a React Application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating my first Public React Application, but I'm facing a problem.

I have a back-end server, in which I request/send a lot of data through my React App.

How to create an endpoint client so that I can change the host (`http://localhost:8000` or `http://foo.com`) and values (`userId` or `commentId`) constantly without having to edit them one by one?

How is this problem solved by large projects?

Is there a Rest API Client that helps me to write my endpoints, being able to prepend the API Host and join the values into a full URL? Like this:

`/users/{id}` -> `https://localhost:8000/users/1`

Comment: I believe you need to setup proxy for your api requests. If you are using `create-react-app`, read [this](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#proxying-api-requests-in-development).

Comment: That's looks good. Can I use it in production environment?

Comment: Basically you need to setup proxy because of dev-server and api-server are working on different ports during development. And if your production server does serve both static and api, it's not an issue, there is no dev-server, so you don't need to proxy api calls.

Comment: Got it. I'm using different servers, so I won't need proxies. I'd like to write my endpoints like `/users/{id}` and get `https://localhost:8000/users/1`. I've trying own implementations, but I failed at all. `fetch` is too simple, `axios` doesn't fit well with my application.

Comment: Having `/users/{id}` as a request address, the browser will make a call to the same host at which the statics have been received. So if `http://foo.com` is the source of statics, then `http://foo.com/users/1` will be the end address of `/users/1` call.

Answer (score 0):

I am running fastAPI for backend and react for frontend.
Frontend build is to be added as static files to fastAPI backend.
I had this challenge of which IP and port customer will run as he has freedom to do it.

So endpoint for production will change and frontend does not know it.

I followed @dhilt answer and it worked. I just left the .env.production as below:

```
//.env.development
REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT=
```

and checked build main.js file it has

```
REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT:""
```

and then run the python unicorn with any ip and port it simply works.

Is this right way to do it or is it wrong practice